# SQLite - creating multiple tables that update or insert

Tags: android, sqlite, date

i am having problem inserting and updating values correctly into the database. I have a database, with two tables each with 3 columns `DATE`, `NUM_X`, `NUM_Y`. The two different tables contain the same columns, the only difference in the way values are inserted is that the `HOURS_TABLE` will take `HH` (the current hour of the day) and `DATE_TABLE` will take a short time string `dd/MM/yyyy`.

The values are not being inserted into new rows, but updating the values of the first row. Both tables currently have only one row.

```
public static final String HOURS_TABLE = "HOURS_TABLE";
public static final String DATE_TABLE = "DATE_TABLE";
public static final String CreateHoursTable = "create table "+ 
HOURS_TABLE +" ("+DATE+" string not null, "+NUM_X+
" integer default 0,"+NUM_Y+" integer default 0)";

public static final String CreateDateTable = "create table "+ 
DATE_TABLE +" ("+DATE+" string not null, "+NUM_X+" 
integer default 0,"+NUM_Y+" integer default 0)";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CreateDateTable);
    db.execSQL(CreateHoursTable);
}
```

Two different kinds of date strings could be passed in, on formatted dd/MM/yyyy (short date string )and another for HH (hours)

```
public long createEntry(int x, int y, String date, int Version_Zero_HoursTable_One_DateTable)
{
    /*
     * first grab the values needed to increment the database values
     * */
    Cursor c ;
    String[] column = new String[]{DATE,NUM_X,NUM_Y};
    if(Version_Zero_HoursTable_One_DateTable == 0)
    {
     c = ourDatabase.query(HOURS_TABLE, column, date, null, null,
            null, null);    
    }
    else
    {
         c = ourDatabase.query(DATE_TABLE, column, date, null, null,
                    null, null);
    }
    int current_x =0;
    int current_y  = 0;
    String current_day = "";
    int iX = c.getColumnIndex(NUM_X);
    int iY = c.getColumnIndex(NUM_Y);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(DATE);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        current_x += c.getInt(iX);
        current_y += c.getInt(iY);
        current_day = c.getString(iDate);
    }
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NUM_X, smokes+current_smokes);
    cv.put(NUM_Y, cravings+current_cravings);
    cv.put(DATE, date);
```

the `WHEREargs` string is my variable for a where clause, so when the selected `DATE` from the database equals `date` it will update that selected column, and if nothing is selected (current_day.equals("")), the statement to insert a new row will execute.

```
    String WHEREargs = DATE+"="+date;
    if(Version_Zero_HoursTable_One_DateTable == 0)
    {
        if(current_day.equals(""))
        {
        return ourDatabase.insert(HOURS_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        else
        {
        return ourDatabase.update(HOURS_TABLE, cv, WHEREargs, null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(current_day.equals(""))
        {
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        else
        {
        return ourDatabase.update(DATE_TABLE, cv, WHEREargs, null);
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated , Thankyou .

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: new rows are not being added, the values in NUM_x, NUM_Y are changed/updated but when the date changed (for hours, when it gets to the next hour it will insert a new row instead of updating the current row)(for date, when the date changes a new row will be inserted inserted instead of updating a current row), i hope that helps explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `date` variable wrong.

A date value such as `24/03/2014` cannot be directly used as a WHERE expression; it would be interpreted as two integer divisions.

Similarly, a string such as `DATE = 24/03/2014` cannot be used as a WHERE expression either, because it compares the value in the date column to a number.

In SQL, strings must be enclosed in `'`single quotes`'`.
However, to avoid formatting problems and SQL injection attacks, it is a better idea to use parameters:

```java
String where = DATE + "= ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { date };
...
db.query(..., where, whereArgs, ...);
```

Comment: is it possible to compare them as strings? so if a string being passed in is not the same as another currently in the table it will create a new row?i am inserting the values into the date column (a text/string column), so i guess what i asking is if that the data in that column is a string, i could compare? no?

Comment: The `date` variable *is* a string. You problem was that improper formatting changed the apaprent type.

Comment: thank you! i used a `where` variable as well as a `whereArgs` variable and everything now checks out, thanks!